# nokogiri doc.xpath('head') returns nil

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to get all the scripts declared in the head section of a given html, but no matter how I try, it always returns nil.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.walmart.com.br/'))

puts doc.at('body') # returns nill

doc.xpath('//html/head').each # this also will never iterate
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page's DOCTYPE isn't valid, so Nokogiri parses the page improperly. A quick, inefficient fix to the problem:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

# Request the HTML before parsing
html = open("http://www.walmart.com.br/").read

# Replace original DOCTYPE with a valid DOCTYPE
html = html.sub(/^<!DOCTYPE html(.*)$/, '<!DOCTYPE html>')

# Parse
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

# Party.
pp doc.xpath("/html/head")
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. After I've changed the doctype I was able to use xpath to go to any dom element.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, when I tried it in script/console, I could indeed get something useful for:

```
doc.at('body')
```

so I'm not sure what's going wrong there for you.

For the html head, I can't get the head element either. html works fine, but head either way doesn't.

I think there's something screwy with that walmart page. I tried doing the same thing for

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://google.com/'))
```

and it worked just fine.
So unless you can figure out what they're doing to stop you from accessing parts of the page... then I don't know.

If you can deal with all scripts from the doc, I found that this one works just fine:

```
doc.xpath('//script')
```

Comment: True! If I call it using //script it gets all scripts on the page, but if I try to give a xpath like //head/script it finds no one.